# Hibernate criteria.setFetchMode("") not working

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, fetch

I have a simple `Criteria`, like this:

```
    final Criteria players = session.createCriteria(Players.class).add(Restrictions.idEq(1));    
    final Criteria team = players.createCriteria("team","team").add(notDeleted());
```

i need a player with `ID=1` and the team is not deleted this is working OK but i need the `Owner of the team and the address of the owner.` strangely this is not working..

```
team.createCriteria("owner").setFetchMode("address",FetchMode.JOIN);
```

This is not working neither:

```
team.createCriteria("owner").setFetchMode("owner.address",FetchMode.JOIN);
```

here i have the owner but i dont have the address. but `Address is not fetched.` Why this is i have the owner i can have the Address??

But this is working.

```
team.setFetchMode("owner",FetchMode.JOIN).setFetchMode("owner.address",FetchMode.JOIN);
```

why this?

any help is hugely appreciate.

thanks a lot.
**UPDATE**

my model is simple.

a team has a lot a player 1-N relationship.
a team has a owner. N-1 relationship.
a owner has a address.

multiple Players->oneTeam->one-owner->oneAddress.

Comment: Post your model structure?

Comment: my question is updated.

Comment: Were you able to make it work?

Comment: my solution was putting the fetching objects in the rootCriteria. like `team.setFetchMode("owner",FetchMode.JOIN).setFetchMode("owner.address",FetchMode.JOIN);`

Comment: @chiperortiz, I suggest you to put your solution as answer for this question

Answer (score 0):

You can put the fetching objects in the `rootCriteria`. Like:

```
team.setFetchMode("owner",FetchMode.JOIN).setFetchMode("owner.address",FetchMode.JOIN);
```